# Big picture discussion for iterative linear solvers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

The Numerical Recipes book provides a **great discussion and insight regarding direct solvers for linear systems** (chap 2). Is there an **equivalent big picture discussion for iterative methods** in the literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the book

*Barrett, Richard; Berry, Michael; Chan, Tony F.; Demmel, James; Donato, June; Dongarra, Jack; Eijkhout, Victor; Pozo, Roldan; Romine, Charles; van der Vorst, Henk*, Templates for the solution of linear systems: building blocks for iterative methods, Philadelphia, PA: SIAM, Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics. xiii, 112 p. (1993). [ZBL0814.65030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0814.65030).

It is dedicated only to the iterative solver, maybe in some way can be consider near Numerical Recipes.

Also maybe can be useful the chapter 4 of:

*Quarteroni, Alfio; Sacco, Riccardo; Saleri, Fausto*, Numerical mathematics, Texts in Applied Mathematics. 37. New York, NY: Springer. xx, 654 p. (2000). [ZBL0957.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0957.65001).

These suggestions are very subjective.

---

If we consider sparse linear system, a very big area where iterative solver are used, I think that the "standard" reference is

*Saad, Yousef*, Iterative methods for sparse linear systems., Philadelphia, PA: SIAM Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics. xviii, 528 p. (2003). [ZBL1031.65046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1031.65046).

You can find the pdf at [this link](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf)

---

I suggest also [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/how-to-choose-a-method-for-solving-linear-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1) of scicomp that it is interesting.

Comment: You rock, thanks a lot! On a more personal matter, checking on the Internet, I have noticed you have worked with Caterina Calgaro in Lille, Northern France and that you are involved in applied mathematics, GPUs... We are a robotic start-up based in Lille, and we may have a job offer for you. What do you think of a phone call to get in touch?

Comment: @arennuit Hi, I left to you my business mail so we can get in touch (info[at]consultingms.it)