# Iterative solvers for large symmetric indefinite linear systems.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, neural-networks, hessian-matrix

I am trying to solve a large-scale symmetric indefinite linear system:

$$Hx=B$$

Here, the matrix $H$ is the Hessian matrix of large neural networks. So, the system is large-scale, symmetric, and sparse.

My question is: which solver is suitable for my problem?

I did some surveys and found some general answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609800/big-picture-discussion-for-iterative-linear-solvers) and [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/how-to-choose-a-method-for-solving-linear-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1). But they are too general that I can not find a specific answer.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: $H$ may be indefinite, but since you're taking Newton steps, you need a strictly convex problem (otherwise you're not looking for the minimum of the quadratic model). So you need to "regularize" the Hessian, that is e.g. you add a multiple of the identity to $H$ to make it positive definite. Then you can use Conjugate Gradient and variants to solve the system.

Comment: @CharlieVanaret Hi, thanks for the advice. What do you mean by 'add a multiple of the identity to H to regularize the Hessian'? Could you specify more details? I am new to this problem.

Comment: Check out the first paragraphs here: https://nhigham.com/2021/02/16/diagonally-perturbing-a-symmetric-matrix-to-make-it-positive-definite/